# openstack swift objects search

Tags: openstack-swift

How to search files (Objects) inside the sub-folder in container. 
my folder structure anu/anusuya/sample.txt.
my curl is < curl -i https://url/Contname/?"limit=2&prefix=sa" >. But it returns empty. If I search **an** it will return the value.

Answer (score 0):

Openstack Swift containers, so far, doesn't have folders, only objects. Although we can see the slashes (anu/anusuya/sample.txt.), they are just part of the object's name.

An alternative solution is to use a tool like grep to filter the response.